# How to work with ActionBarActivity instead of Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse for android development and last time I used it couple of months ago with API-17. But today when installing new updates from SDK manager, I am trying to create a new project. And after creation my activity is extending ActionBarActivity instead of activity. And its showing errors. Any solutions?

Plus I got the below 2 lines of importing showing error:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide any logcat of the error or precise why you cannot run the app?

Comment: have you referenced AppCompat?

Comment: @Raghunandan whao raghunandan!! I am fan of urs, have gone through a few tutorials of urs. Anyways , yes I just created a library project now and added the library project to my app project. now its showing a exclamatory sign on top of my project folder in eclipse, all errors r gone. What to do now?

Comment: you haven't referenced AppCompat properly. Follow https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I have done it following the link you sent. Still the same. Do, I need to update anything from SDK manager?

Comment: @shaon007 need a screen shot of java build path libraries tab expanded to know more.

Comment: @Raghunandan , sorry for delay editing. I have given screen shot of library tab of java build path. Actually I tried to update all things in sdk manager, thought that will work. But, same error is showing. help me out

Comment: @shaon007 the errors show you haven't referenced appcompat properly

Comment: @Raghunandan , can you please explain me, why I need to do so much hard work to create a new project? It should be done as before, just by giving name and clicking next next..

Comment: @shaon007 i can't answer that. the why part ask a google engineer. it isn't hard to reference a library. You should be able to do it following the docs

Comment: @Raghunandan ,  I have followed the android developers site. I have done all the parts of - Adding libraries with resources for eclipse. Still not working. What to do?

Comment: @shaon007 Simply remove your `Android Dependencies` library and then try to clean your project.

Comment: @shaon007 Have you added the library project of `appcompat_v7` in your workspace?

Comment: @GrIsHu , ya it worked. Which means I don't have to Add libraries like AppCompact as below?  developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: You are supposed to add that library if you are using actionbar or fragments below api 11. The references for which it was showing error was the copy of the `appcompat_v7` library which was automatically created by eclipse. If you add the library make sure you add original `appcompat_v7` not `appcompat_v7_2` or `appcompat_v7_3`.

Comment: @GrIsHu , man its getting complicated for me. I have imported the android-support-v7-appcompat in eclipse already as per developers site. Why do I need to add appcompat_v7 again and how?

Comment: There no need to add `appcompat_v7` if you have already added `android-support-v7-appcompat` . @shaon007

Comment: @GrIsHu , sorry just frequently asking u questions but I just want to make the things clear to myself. What if I didn't add the android-support-v7-appcompat and want to add appcompat_v7? or is the android-support-v7-appcompat the original?

Comment: If you only add `appcompat_v7` or only add `android-support-v7-appcompat` there is no difference. You can add any one of the library in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually remove these if you dont need them, but they are very useful as it creates overflow menu, action bar for lower android version of its own

Answer (score 0):

Import the AppCompat library into Eclipse (you may have to download it from the SDK Manager first). ActionBarActivity works the same as a normal Activity, except some method names are slightly different, e.g. `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.