# Why is the simple code not running?

Tags: android

Previously I have done some code with android using sdk 17, where the activity extended Activity. But yesterday I updated everything from my sdk manager. And first problem I was facing was that I couldn't build application with min sdk less then API-14. So, I used min sdk-14 and proceeded. When I gave button, textview etc in main_fragmet - the application was running. But the problem occurs when I am trying to give value in textview from code in mainActivity. Below is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvw);

    t.setText("Shaonn");
    //t.setText("Shaon");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();


    }

}
```

in AVD its not running and error showin unfortunately the app has stoped.

**Error from logcat:**

```
05-15 06:46:21.812: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd5418 that was originally bound here
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd5418 that was originally bound here
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run  (FutureTask.java:234)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-15 06:46:23.412: E/StrictMode(555): null
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Do you've TextView placed in activity_main.xml or fragement...xml ? Post your logcat as said by @Gr.....

Comment: Edited my question. And my TextView is in fragment.xml

Comment: If your textview in in fragment.xml file then you can not access your textview in mainactivity. I should be inside placefragment file.

Comment: change your emulator settings to use lcd_density, try to run the same code on device.

Comment: placefragment file? Is it inside onCreateView of class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment ? I tried that too but not working. Ya, if I take the textView to main.xml thn its working, But how do I do this for fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For error:

```
Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd5418 that was originally bound here
05-15 06:46:23.382: E/ActivityThread(555): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd5418 that was originally bound here
```

Try disabling host GPU in the Emulator options, it will fix the problem.

**Also,**
If your `TextView` in in `fragment.xml` file then you can not access your `TextView` in `Mainactivity`. I should be inside placefragment file.

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
            TextView  t=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtvw);

              t.setText("Shaonn");
      return v;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped me. Can you please give another solution to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647513/how-to-work-with-actionbaractivity-instead-of-activity?noredirect=1#comment36345176_23647513

Answer (score 0):

That's the issue...You've your textview in frgament.xml but you are initializing it in activity_main.xml..remove the code from here

and Paste it in fragment

```
t=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtvw);

    t.setText("Shaonn");
```